# Unable to register with subscription-manager on redhat 7.4 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: redhat

I am new to RedHat Linux and installed a 7.4 version on VirtualBox. According to the steps for RedHat installation, I need to first subscribe to RedHat for downloading on RedHat.

The command used is

```
subscription-manager register --username xxxxxxx --password xxxxxxx --auto-attach
```

and the output is

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

The user and password are correct in the red hat website.
I had gone through RedHat Bugzilla tickets and solution provided by customer-support, but nothing worked for me.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Got the solution and now the issue has been resolved.

To use RedHat no-cost subscription one needs to activate the RedHat account with https://developers.redhat.com/ as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will happen if you have another system registered (i.e. you stood up a VM, had issues, and destroyed it).

Go into your account on RedHat.com -> Customer Portal
Check two things:

1. Subscriptions - Make sure you have at least one active subscription
2. Systems - Select the systems, remove them.

Go back into your RHEL server and type `subscription-manager register --auto-attach` and you will be prompted for username/password for your RedHat account.

This should now work successfully.

This is an old question, but I had the same issue and did not find any helpful answers, so leaving this for any others that may have this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in my case with:

`sudo subscription-manager clean`

then registering again

RHEL 7.9